Will a recent B2 travel to the same location as my F1 college application affect the decision
I am planning to travel to Chicago for a vacation in the coming months on a recently issued B2 visa. I am also considering masters from the US next year and Illinois is one of the schools I have in mind. At the time of an F1 application next year, would the last travel to Chicago be of any concern?
I have read about rejected Change of status from B2 to F1 in the US (which is NOT my scenario) due to "intent of education" during the B2 travel.

Questions about student visas are better for [expatriates.se].

It depends. You are writing just about location, but visas depend also on other facts you didn't mention. What is the purpose of your B2 travel? Note: probably you will asked at immigration. Visiting the city (also with a plan to stay legally there with a F1 visas is fine, taking lectures until you get the F1 is more problematic).

It should be fine.  Rejected change of status implies that the authorities determined (rightly or wrongly) that the student entered the US in B-2 status with the intention of changing status.  It is perfectly acceptable to enter in B-2 status with the intention of leaving and returning later in F-1 status.  In fact, B-2 is the status you would use to visit and evaluate universities as a prospective student.
